# PE header ImageBase offset

Tags: hex, exe, offset, portable-executable

I want to ask why ImageBase offset in one PE header is equal to 32h and other 35h

[IMAGE:calc.exe  offset 32h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfKTc.png)

[IMAGE:ser2.exe offset 35h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdzDm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because these were made by different toolchain. The first one is extremely likely cl.exe+link.exe and the other one may have been made by gcc+ld.